# OpenGL ES Framebuffer creation problem

Tags: c++, opengl-es, objective-c

I'm having some problems porting my D3D code to OpenGL ES. I have a Graphics Device class that encapsulates all rendering commands. The code below is in an ObjC++ file.

The problem code is the called to get the render buffer width and height. It doesn't actually return any value in the w or h GLints.

It should be noted that the code below is from an older iPhone project, and it works there. Am I missing something really stupid?

Checking the framebuffer status returns a value of complete, since OpenGL ES seems quite happy to initialize a depth buffer with the garbage w and h values I pass to it!

```
bool GraphicsDevice::Initialize(id<EAGLDrawable> eaglLayer)  
{
   EAGLContext *context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
   if(context == nil)
   { 
      return false;
   }

   [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

   this->eaglContext = context;

   glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
   glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
   [eaglContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:eaglLayer];

   GLint w, h;
   glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &w);
   glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &h);

   SetWidth(static_cast<unsigned int>(w));
   SetHeight(static_cast<unsigned int>(h));

  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER,    renderBuffer);

   glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
   glBindBuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
   glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, w, h);

   glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);

   GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
   if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
   {
      System::Log("Framebuffer not complete");
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to create a framebuffer from an EAGLLayer that already had a framebuffer created from it. I don't know why OpenGL ES was saying the framebuffer was complete and not setting an error right away, but there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

In the book "iPhone 3D Programming" there are examples of this. The author uses the OES extensions. Like

```
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &m_renderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, m_renderbuffer);
```

or

```
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &m_framebuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, m_framebuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,
                             GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,
                             GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES,
                             m_renderbuffer);
```

I've tested these commands:

```
GLint w, h;
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &w);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &h);
```

and the width and height are correct.

You can download the book examples [here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/)

See the "HelloArrow" project. Within the class RenderingEngine1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Those functions are ES1 only. I came back to my issue a couple of days ago and discovered that some legacy code was still trying to create a framebuffer with my UIView.